# Why are WMP playlists incomplete when streamed over network?

Tags: windows-7, nas, windows-media-player, audio-streaming, media-server

My DLNA receiver ([Marantz 1602](http://us.marantz.com/us/Products/Pages/ProductDetails.aspx?Catid=AVReceivers&SubCatId=0&ProductId=NR1602)) does not display all items from my Windows Media Player (v12.0.7601.17514) playlists. Some playlists show all, some show only a few, some show none. This applies to playlists that are stored on and streamed from my Windows 7 PC, as well as to the same playlists that are stored on and streamed from a NAS media server ([WD MyBook Live 2TB](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=280)).

The playlists are in default `.WPL` file format, and I cannot find any difference in `SMIL` XML-format of the contents of the files:

```
<?wpl version="1.0"?>
<smil>
    <head>
        <meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Windows Media Player -- 12.0.7601.17514"/>
        <meta name="ItemCount" content="99"/>
        <author/>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <seq>
            <media src="..\Artist\Song.mp3" cid="{GUID}" tid="{GUID}"/>
            <media src="..\Artist\Album\Song.mp3" cid="{GUID}" tid="{GUID}"/>
            <media src="..\Artist\Song.mp3" tid="{GUID}"/>
            <media src="..\Artist\Album\Song.mp3" tid="{GUID}"/>
        </seq>
    </body>
</smil>
```

All 99 items are in either one of those 4 formats, and all src attributes use relative paths.

What could be the cause of these incomplete playlists at my receiver?

Comment: Not a solution, but if the receiver supports M3U playlists can you try those instead?

Comment: @Kar Thanks, that's a fantastic working alternative!

Comment: Excellent, and as a bonus there's *far* more widespread support for the M3U format as compared to MS' WPL. Edit: Perhaps you can report this WPL issue as a bug to Marantz.